# Migrating a submodule's gitdir to 'in-tree'

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule in my repo with a .git file that has just one line

```
gitdir: ../.git/modules/mysubmodule
```

However, the CI runner of gitlab seems to have problems with this `gitdir` statement, so I want to move `../.git/modules/mysubmodule` to `./mysubmodule/.git`.

I did this using `mv`
I did not use `git mv`, because this command complains with

```
fatal: cannot move directory over file, source=.git/modules/mysubmodule, destination=mysubmodule/.git
```

And I also removed the `worktree` line from the `mysubmodule/.git/config` file.

However, when I want to commit the changes (either to the superproject or the submodule), git lists no changes to commit.

This is why I am wondering how can I move the gitdir to another path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing `.git` in `./mysubmodule/.git` git still thinks `mysubmodule` as a submodule and doesn't show it as a part of superrepo.

If you want to remove submodule(s) and re-add them directly yoy should [remove submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/7976758) and add them without `.git` subdirectory.

Or switch from `git submodule` to `git subtree`. See https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt and https://medium.com/@v/git-subtrees-a-tutorial-6ff568381844

Comment: Sounds great, I removed the submodule but how do I add it without creating a .git file with a gitdir entry?

Comment: Copy code and not `.git/. Then you will have to update everything manually.